# Service synchronization issue

Tags: spring-boot, architecture, synchronization, microservices, distributed-computing

I've created two services.

One of them (scheduler) only requests to the other (backoffice) for performing some "large" operations.

When backoffice receives a request:

1. first creates a mark (key on redis) in order to set that the process has started.

Each time a request is reached:

1. backoffice checks if the mark exist.

   - When it exists means that the previous process has not yet finished, and escape it.
   - Perform the large process.
   - When process is finished, the previous key in redis is removed.

It would be something like this:

```
if (key exists)
  return;

make long process... (1);

remove key;
```

The problem arises when service is destroyed when the process has not already finished and then it doesn't removes the mark on redis. It means the process will never run again.

Is there any way to solve this kind of problems?

Comment: What happens if the process runs twice or more then 1 time?  Does the key identify which exact process is running or is it just the same key for all?

Comment: It's the same key for all.

Comment: lot's of options...the 'key' could contain unique _scheduler-service-id_ ... in the process _'backoffice checks if the mark exist'_ add an additional check if service is still alive...

Answer (score 0):

The way to solve this problem is use an existing engine as building custom scalable and robust solution for reliable service orchestration is really hard.

I recommend looking at Uber [Cadence Workflow](https://cadenceworkflow.io/) which would allow to convert your pseudocode into a real production application with minor changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can fire a background job that updates timestamp under the key, e.g. every minute.

When service attempts to start the process it must verify key existence (as it does now) + timestamp under the key. If it is more than 1 minute ago then the previous attempt is stale and you can start over.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should be using a messaging queue to schedule tasks for the back office service. Queuing solutions like RabbitMQ allow you to manually acknowledge (or “ack”) that the process is complete. Whenever a subscriber crashes, the queue detects that the connection dropped without acknowledgement and will re-enqueue the same task which will be picked up by the next available subscriber. Here’s another thread talking about this problem specifically focused on messaging queues:

[What happens to fetched messages when RabbitMQ consumer crashes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42375034/what-happens-to-fetched-messages-when-rabbitmq-consumer-crashes)